# My numpy and pytorch codes have totally different results

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I wanted to calculate the sum of 1st to K-th power of an array and equally calculate the sum of 1st to k-th power of a tensor. I found out that the following codes and their results are totally different and I don't know why.

I debugged the code and I know that the results are equal in the first round.

Numpy code:

```
adj_k_prob = adj_prob
adj_k_pow =  adj_prob
for i in range(K):
    adj_k_pow = np.matmul(adj_prob, adj_k_pow)
    adj_k_prob += adj_k_pow
```

Pytorch code:

```
adj_k_prob = adj_prob_tensor
adj_k_pow = adj_prob_tensor
for i in range(K):
    adj_k_pow = torch.matmul(adj_prob_tensor, adj_k_pow)
    adj_k_prob += adj_k_pow
```

The value of adj_prob_tensor and adj_prob at the start of loop are as follow:

```
tensor([[0.0000, 0.1429, 0.1429, 0.1429, 0.1429, 0.1429, 0.1429, 0.1429],
    [0.2500, 0.0000, 0.2500, 0.2500, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.2500],
    [0.2500, 0.2500, 0.0000, 0.2500, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.2500],
    [0.2500, 0.2500, 0.2500, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.2500],
    [0.5000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.5000, 0.0000],
    [0.5000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.5000, 0.0000],
    [0.3333, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.3333, 0.3333, 0.0000, 0.0000],
    [0.2500, 0.2500, 0.2500, 0.2500, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000]])
```

Is there anything that I should check for it?

Comment: Aw, to calculate the power, shouldn't you use `=` rather than `+=` as assignment operator in both your loops? Not sure this solves your discrepancy problem though.

Comment: @DavideFiocco So many thanks for your help. Actually my problem is that why the two codes are not equal and what the difference is between them. But again thanks for your help

Comment: @DavideFiocco I edited the question thanks.

Comment: Can you provide examples of `adj_prob` and `adj_prob_tensor` that give you that discrepancy? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in using assignment. I should have used .clone() for pytorch and .copy() in numpy.